# Trying to use props in order to display new comments (React JS)

Tags: reactjs, comments, react-props, display

I am trying to display new comments instantly when they are created. Currently, it doesn't work.

This is me code. On my PostPage, I added "fetchComments={fetchComments}" to my CommentForm tag. And on my CommentForm, I used props.fetchComments() in the handleSubmit.

Do you have a solution for this ?

My PostPage (parent component) :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useParams, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { API_URL } from '../config'
import { Skeleton } from '@material-ui/lab'
import { Grid, Button } from '@material-ui/core'
import { AiFillCaretLeft } from "react-icons/ai"
import List from '@material-ui/core/List'
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem'
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText'
import ListItemAvatar from '@material-ui/core/ListItemAvatar'
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'
import CommentForm from '../Components/Forms/CommentForm'
import PostsAPI from '../Services/PostsAPI'
import CommentsAPI from '../Services/CommentsAPI'

export default function PostPage() {

    const {id} = useParams()
    const [post, setPost] = useState(null)
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
    const [comments, setComments] = useState([])
    
    const fetchPost = async () => {
        const data = await PostsAPI.findOne(id);
        setPost(data)
        setIsLoading(true)
    }
    
    const fetchComments = async (props) => {
        try{
            const comments = await CommentsAPI.findAll()
            setComments(comments.data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPost();
        fetchComments();
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <nav>
                <Link to="/">
                    <Button variant="contained" color="primary"><AiFillCaretLeft /><span>Back</span></Button>
                </Link>
            </nav>
            <Grid container spacing = {2}>
                <Grid item sm={6}>
                    <div className='postImg'>
                        {isLoading ? <img src={API_URL + post.data.attributes.image.data[0].attributes.formats.small.url} alt={post.data.attributes.title} /> : <Skeleton variant="rect" width="100%" height={400} />}
                    </div>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item sm={6}>
                    <h1>{isLoading ? post.data.attributes.title : <Skeleton variant="text" width={300} height={80} />}</h1>
                    <p>{isLoading ? post.data.attributes.content : 
                        <>
                            <Skeleton variant="text" height={25}/>
                            <Skeleton variant="text" width="60%" height={25}/>
                        </>
                    }</p>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                <Grid item md={6}>
                    <CommentForm fetchComments={fetchComments} />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item md={6}>
                    {<List>
                        {comments.map((comment, i) => (
                            <ListItem key={i} alignItems="flex-start">
                                <ListItemAvatar>
                                <Avatar alt="Avatar" src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg" />
                                </ListItemAvatar>
                                <ListItemText
                                primary={comment.attributes.pseudo}
                                secondary={
                                    <React.Fragment>
                                    <Typography
                                        component="span"
                                        variant="body2"
                                        color="textPrimary"
                                    >
                                    </Typography>
                                    "{comment.attributes.content}"
                                    </React.Fragment>
                                }
                                />
                            </ListItem>
                        ))}
                    </List>}
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The CommentForm (child component) :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core'
import CommentsAPI from '../../Services/CommentsAPI'

export default function CommentForm(props) {

    const [comment, setComment] = useState({})
    const {id} = useParams()

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        try {
            CommentsAPI.create(JSON.parse(`{"data":${JSON.stringify(comment)}}`));
            props.fetchComments()
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const {name, value} = event.currentTarget
        setComment({
            ...comment,
            [name]: value,
            "post":id
        })
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div>
                <TextField 
                    id="pseudo" 
                    label="Pseudo" 
                    type="text" 
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    name="pseudo"
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <TextField
                    id="comment"
                    label="Comment"
                    multiline
                    minRows={2}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    name="content"
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">
                    Send
                </Button>
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: It seem you have forgotten to set the `props` as `CommentForm` parameter, like this `function CommentForm(props){...}`

Comment: Thank you Saeed Shamloo. I just added it in my code. However, I am wondering how I can display a new comment instantly after it's been created...

Comment: But now you've implemented some api call, you mean you want to remove them?

Comment: No, otherwise I won't have my comments displayed anymore. The purpose of my ticket is that I am looking for how I can see my new comment without having to refresh the app. :)

Comment: if `CommentsAPI.create` is an async function you need just to add `await` keyword before calling this method, like this: `await CommentsAPI.create(...)` and other parts should work crrectly.
`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
const [apiData, setAPIData] = useState();
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
        CommentsAPI.create(JSON.parse(`{"data":${JSON.stringify(comment)}}`));
        const data = await props?.fetchComments();
        //-- 
        setAPIData(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
return (
  { data.map( item => {----} )
  }
)
```

Thanks.
~ Storm In Talent

Comment: Thank you StormyTalent. Is it possible to add { data.map( item => {----} ) } in the PostPage ? The CommentForm only contains the form to create my comments.

Comment: It worked by adding "await" before "CommentsAPI.create". Thank you for your help Storm In Talent !